# How to load pictures using JPEG codec in java?

Tags: java

what is the procedure to loading a picture by using of JPEG codec?

Comment: This poster has asked about 4 questions on the same topic (although it looks like 2 have been deleted). Not once has the posted bothered to respond to a single posting. I'm amazed people still waste time answering his questions. And YES ImageIO was suggested in at least 2 of the other postings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ImageIO.read(file)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.File%29)

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied File with an ImageReader  chosen automatically from among those currently registered

`JPEGImageReader` is automatically registered (as well as BMP, GIF, PNG and WBPM).

Comment: one thing I like about this is this class reads and writes multiple file formats without needing to load the specific file support.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javax.imageio.ImageIO class.

Answer (score 0):

use ImageIO class